# E-Mail Timer Jobs Are Not Firing

Tags: 2007, timer-jobs

In a MOSS 2007 environment, I've setup Incoming E-Mail Settings in Central Admin and two timer jobs were subsequently created:

1) Windows SharePoint Services Get Incoming E-Mail Configuration

2) Windows SharePoint Services Incoming E-Mail

Neither one of these have ran. They both have N/A next to the value for Last run time. I've restarted the SharePoint timer service (owstimer) several times but with no luck.

**Is there a way to manually start a timer job using STSADM?**

**Are there any known reasons why these timer jobs would not be starting?**